# open() blocks when trying to open pipe for reading

Tags: c++, linux, pipe

I have two processes, a server and a client, that should communicate via pipes (C++, Linux).
The server opens the pipe with the `O_RDONLY` flag, and the client with `O_WRONLY`.
However, the server blocks at the `open` function, while the client seems to run successfully (the `open` function returns success and so do the `write` functions).

I have read that if the `O_NONBLOCK` flag is set, the read function will continue, but I don't want it to continue if no client is connected - it is ok to block **until a client is connected**, but in my case it remains blocked even after the client finishes running...

Can you plese tell me what I'm doing wrong...?

Here is the code:

```
// Server side
int pipe;
int status, nr_read = 0;

status = mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0666);
if (status < 0)
{
    // If the file already exists, delete it
    unlink(FIFO_NAME);

    // Try again
    status = mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0666);

    if(status < 0)
    {
        printf("mkfifo error: %d\n", status);
        return status;
    }
}

pipe = open(FIFO_NAME, O_RDONLY);
printf("Never gets here...\n");
[...]
nr_read = read(pipe, my_char_array, CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE);
[...]
close(pipe);
unlink(FIFO_NAME);
```

It never gets to the "printf" line...

```
// Client side:
int pipe, nr_sent = 0;
int status = 0;

pipe = open(FIFO_NAME, O_WRONLY);
if (pipe < 0)
{
    printf("open fifo error: %d\n", status);
    return pipe;
}

[...]
nr_sent = write(pipe, my_char_array, CHAR_ARRAY_LENGTH);
[...]
close(pipe);
```

---

**EDIT**

I didn't mention the line
`#define FIFO_NAME "MYFIFO"`

... and here was the problem:
as Jody Hagins said, the path being a relative one and the processes being started from different folders, they were trying to open different files.

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentially recreate the FIFO after the client has connected?

Comment: During debug, I wait for the server to get to the "open" line, hit continue, and then run the client... so I believe not...

Comment: Have you checked that the file is actually created by `mkfifo`?

Comment: Don't you have to create the FIFO on the client side as well?

Comment: @tetsuo000 No, I don't think so... The client should be able to open the pipe by it's name.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You're right, `[ -p $FILE ]` returns false even if the `mkfifo` returned success in the server... Hmm...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The read-side will not complete a blocking open until the write-side has completed the pipe.

If you do not want this functionality, then open the read-side `O_NONBLOCK`, and use `select` to determine when the write-side has established a connection and process input accordingly.

**EDIT**

Oops.  Just noticed that you said your server is not completing the open even after running the client.  That's strange.  I just cut/paste your code and after adding the missing header includes, and the missing variable/constants, ran the server/client and they operated as expected.

The server waited for the client, and when the client ran, the server completed the open and read the data.

Check your file to make sure you have an actual FIFO.

You should see something like this:

```
> ls -lat /tmp/FIFO
prw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2012-09-11 10:22 /tmp/FIFO


> stat /tmp/FIFO
  File: `/tmp/FIFO'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   fifo
Device: 6802h/26626d    Inode: 186603      Links: 1
Access: (0644/prw-r--r--)  Uid: (10042/ user)   Gid: (10042/ user)
Access: 2012-09-11 10:22:48.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2012-09-11 10:22:48.000000000 -0400
Change: 2012-09-11 10:22:48.000000000 -0400
```

Comment: Solved, thank you for your example. I renamed the FIFO from "MYFIFO" (a #define I did not post in the question, unfortunately) to "/tmp/FIFO", as in your example, and now it does not block anymore... If the `open` function necessarily needs a full path, than why did it block when trying to open for reading and did not block when opening for writing?

Comment: `open()` does not require a full path.  However, you must make sure that the paths in both the client and server reference the same file.  Also, some file systems can not support a FIFO file, but that should cause an error when creating the file.  My best guess is that your server and client were not actually referring to the same file (maybe they were being run from different directories, and since they were using relative file names the server was creating a new FIFO, and the client was using one that already existed).  Anyway, glad to help.

Comment: Yes, that was it, they were being ran from different directories. Thank you!