# How to distinguish fifo openable vs readable content?

Tags: linux, nonblocking, mkfifo

I'm a bit new to `fifo`s on Linux and also have limited experience with `select()`.

I've [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371088/open-blocks-when-trying-to-open-pipe-for-reading) that calling `open()` on the read-end of a FIFO will block until the write end completes the pipe.

One can open the read end of the fifo with `O_NONBLOCK` in order to not block at `open()`. You can then `select()` with the fifo's file descriptor in the readfds in order to know when the file is openable - true?

What I'm confused by now, though: after knowing that the file is openable, I'd subsequently like to know that the fifo has readable contents, i.e. I'd like to know that `read()` on the fifo file descriptor would not block. For this, I would have thought to `select()` with the fifo file descriptor in the readfds - but this seems to conflict with using `select()` to know if the file is openable.

So I guess to summarize my question: how can I use `select()` to know 1) when `open()` on the read end of a fifo would not block, and 2) when `read()` on a fifo would not block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption that `select()` unblocks on the read end to indicate that the fifo is openable appears to be incorrect. It looks like `select()` unblocks on the read end only when there is data to read in the fifo.

This test code demonstrates my observation: as is, the `select()` times out; uncomment the single commented line, and `select()` unblocks on the fifo file descriptor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <ctime>

#define FIFO "/tmp/foo"

void* sr1( void* arg )
{
  mkfifo( FIFO, 0777 );
  sleep( 3 );
  int fd = open ( FIFO, O_WRONLY );
  //write( fd, "a", 1 );
  std::cout << "t1 opened " << fd << std::endl;
  sleep( 3 );
  close( fd );
  std::cout << "t1 closed " << fd << std::endl;
  return NULL;
}

void* sr2( void* arg )
{
  int fd = open( FIFO, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK );
  std::cout << "t2 opened " << fd << std::endl;
  fd_set readfds;
  FD_ZERO( &readfds );
  FD_SET( fd, &readfds );
  struct timeval ts = { 5, 0 };
  std::cout << "t2 waiting now" << std::endl;
  select( fd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &ts );
  if ( FD_ISSET( fd, &readfds ) )
  {
    std::cout << "t2 " << fd << " set so select() unblocked" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "t2 " << " select() unblocked at timeout" << std::endl;
  }
  close( fd );
  std::cout << "t2 closed " << fd << std::endl;
  return NULL;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  pthread_t t1;
  pthread_t t2;

  pthread_create( &t1, NULL, sr1, NULL );
  pthread_create( &t2, NULL, sr2, NULL );

  pthread_join( t1, NULL );
  pthread_join( t2, NULL );
}
```